# SMSC spoofing attack

Tags: network, attacks

I attended a seminar on Telecom networks few day back and there I came to know how vulnerable our signalling network (SS7/ SIGTRAN) is.

The speaker discussed an attack in which a spoofed [SMSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_service_center) is connected to a legitimate network's SMSC and all the traffic routed to the legitimate one can be retrieved at fake SMSC. In this way, an attacker can exploit user details.

I wonder how can this attack take place without operator's knowledge and intervention? or even if its possible to conduct this attack or not?

Comment: This might be a question for follow-up with the speaker

Comment: True. I wanted to but had another imp commitment so skipped the Q/A session

Comment: You can still contact the presenter

Comment: I don't have details. If I have it then why would I post here, sir

Comment: You would be surprised how many people post questions to which they can easily get answers.

Comment: Was the seminar public? Can you post a link to the event?

Answer (score 0):

It the absence of Signalling firewall(SS7,Diameter and GTP) in the receiving network, if an attacker uses a software that has the capability to send SS7 Map messages. The attacker can send Map messages that are expected from SMSC of external network towards the receiving network. 
The attackers can send MAP messages with spoof CgPA such as ATI to get the subscribers locations, since there is not firewall, the Core CS network is not smart enought to detects these attrocities, unless you have a very smart telecom engineers that is monitoring the traffic 24/7 and are actively blocking traffic from operators that does not have certain traffic aggrement with them.